# Sms in vtiger with custom provider

Tags: php, vtigercrm

Dears
I have vtiger crm i need to intgrate sms provider with vtiger all i got from my provider this link

http://www.alfa-cell.com/api/msgSend.php?mobile=MYUSERNAME&password=MYPASSWORD&numbers=966550502265&sender=MYUSERNAME&msg=TestMSM&applicationType=24&lang=2

From web i can send message but how i can make this url in vtiger to i can send message

Note.. Am not devolper if some one assist me thank him very much

Answer (score 0):

Refer this documentation on how to integrate sms provider with vtiger

https://www.vtiger.com/docs/add-sms-provider